# if statement directed to two different PHP File

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi am new to programming, and I trying to show different PHP files using if statement, I want to show the finaloffline.php if I input the number 22 while I want to show the Delayed report if I input different number
Here is my code.
is this possible?

```
<h1>input Number</h1>
<?PHP
if ($myVariable == "22")
{
echo '<form method="post" action="Finaloffline.php">';
}

else
{
echo '<form method="post" action="DelayedReport.php">';
}
?>

<?php $myVariable = "";?>
 <input type="text" name="text" value="<?php echo $myVariable; ?>">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: (1) Please change `<?PHP` to `<?php`   (2) one of the ways is to dynamically change the action url on your form submission, say by javascript. If you tried and still not successful please let us know

Comment: hello, even I change the <?PHP to <?PHP, Still not working. Thanks

Comment: please try my suggested answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (dynamically change the action url on your form submission, by javascript.)

```
<h1>input Number</h1>

<form action="#"  method="post" id="searchform">
<input type="text" name="text" id="data1" value="">
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:chgAction();">Submit</button>
</form>



<script>

function chgAction()
{
     if( document.getElementById("data1").value=="22" ) {
       document.getElementById("searchform").action = "Finaloffline.php";
        document.getElementById("searchform").submit();

     } else {
        document.getElementById("searchform").action = "DelayedReport.php";
        document.getElementById("searchform").submit();

      }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you so much for the idea, I am now done with this module. it is a big help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>input Number</h1>
<?php
    if($_REQUEST['enter']){
        if($_REQUEST['number'] == "22"){
            header("Location: Finaloffline.php");
            exit();
        }else{
            header("Location: DelayedReport.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Enter number">
    <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to determine the PHP files submitted to different branches by the input value?

If it is

Here's the answer. You need jQuery to implement this function:

body content

```
<h1>input Number</h1>
<form action="" id="my_form" method="post" name="form">
    <input type="text" name="val" value="">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

js content

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#my_form").click(function(e){
        var val = $("input[name='val']").val();
        if (val == 22) {
            $('form[id=my_form]').attr('action','Finaloffline.php');
        } else {
            $('form[id=my_form]').attr('action','DelayedReport.php');
        }
    });
</script>
```